# MongoDB aggregate pipeline to get number of employees for each distinct state

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to show the total number of employees for each state, only for companies in the USA.
So it would look like this but for all the states included in the dataset: (Sample numbers)

```
AZ : 1234
CA : 30000
FL : 43439
```

A have a collection with documents structured like so:

[image]

My first step was to simply use $match to only get companies with an office.country_code of "USA".
Now I need to count all the employees for each state and group them. I also need to list each state without duplication. I have tried $group but the nested offices array is giving me trouble. There are also situations where some companies have multiple offices in the offices array.

[image]

I guess my first step would be to display the distinct states using $group. How would I get the distinct list of states when the offices.state_code is nested in an array element, and sometimes there are multiple array elements.

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LA9tQxxthYt)

Hopefully, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post sample data as `text`? You can also use https://mongoplayground.net as sandbox and post shared link

Comment: Like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/LA9tQxxthYt

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now, let's check what you are trying to get.

Comment: Yes I need to show the total number of employees by state for all companies that have offices in the USA. So I would need to use $group to get each unique state I am assuming, and then somehow count the number of employees for those states($sum?), and finally display the results. The nesting and multiple offices per company is confusing me.

Comment: Take a look [https://mongoplayground.net/p/dM5maKRUs75](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dM5maKRUs75). Now, what do you need to do?

Comment: I am trying to show the number of employees for each state. So, of course, there are more states and more companies.So I would need to sum all the employees for offices in CA for example, and display it like "CA : 12332". It is just weird because when there are multiple offices with different states, there is only one object for number_of_employees. I am assuming if there are multiples states and offices like the one in the playground, the value 120 would be added to each of those states like: VA : 120, NY : 120, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$unwind` operator to flatten `offices`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$offices"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "offices.country_code": "USA"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$offices.state_code",
      employees: {
        $sum: "$number_of_employees"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y56KY3dOYyu)

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about $unwind, would have saved me a lot of time. Although it still does not make sense why there is only number of employees for the company instead of each office. Leads to duplicates... thanks though.